# Optimization Multiple Constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, quadratic-programming, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a linear algebra problem: an optimization problem and I am using CVXOPT. I've split the problem into 3 components

In its simplest form, The general formulation for CVXOPT is \begin{align}\min&\quad\frac12x^\top Px+q^\top x\\\text{s.t.}&\quad Gx\le h\\&\quad Ax=b\end{align}

**1st problem component**
First of all I have to minimize, subject to constraint a very simple problem defined as following

P=

```
|   S   |
```

q=

```
|   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   |
```

b=

```
|   1   |
```

G=

```
|   r   |
|   -I  |
```

b=

```
|   rmin    0   |
```

I have coded this and it is working perfectly

**2nd problem component**
The second problem I have is to transform a non convex problem into convex and linear so that the turnover generated by the optimisation problem it is constrained to a max value. In this case I have modelled and coded the problem as following and again all works fine

P=

```
  | S   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
```

q=

```
|   -x1 0   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   0   0   |
|   I   I   -I  |
```

b=

```
|   1   x0  0   |
```

G=

```
|   0   1   1   |
|   -I  0   0   |
|   0   -I  0   |
|   0   0   -I  |
```

h=

```
|   T   0   0   |
```

**3rd problem component**
The third problem which I am struggling with (to solve) is to combine the two above. What I have done, which is obviously not correct as it turns to be a singular matrix is doing the following

P=

```
|   S   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
```

q=

```
|   -x1 0   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   0   0   |
|   I   I   -I  |
```

b=

```
|   1   x0  0   |
```

G=

```
|   0   1   1       |
|   -I  0   0       |
|   0   -I  0       |
|   0   0   -I      |
|   0   0   rmin    |
|   0   0   -I      |
```

h=

```
|   T   0   0   rmin    0   |
```

As I think the problem of the singularity comes from G, can anyone help me formulating the third problem in a correct way?

Comment: Isn't P supposed to be square? Shouldn't Ax have the same dimensionality (2) as b (which has 3 instead)?

Comment: I don't find this to be the clearest exposition. Perhaps you can post your code, complete with all input data and output, including error messages? You might find it easier to use CVXPY than CVXOPT. CVXPY provides a higher level, easier to understand, interface than does CVXOPT. CVXPY can call CVXOPT as solver, or call any of a large number of other solvers.